# How can I save my changes on pod to do a URL redirect on nginx ingress?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, nginx-ingress

I'm new working with docker and kubernetes, and I have some problems on my company environment to save somethings.

I have my environment running on a EKS and I need to do a redirect URL on my NGINX ingress-controller, but I couldn't save my changes on environment.
I've tried to update rules on my nginx.conf and push a new docker image to deploy on my pod with **kubectl set image**. The new image was applied when I ran **kubectl describe pod** on my deployment and my pod, but changes didn't work, nothing was changed.

Is there another way to update pods image on kubernetes?

Comment: How do you normally deploy software?  I'd expect a Deployment's `image:` to normally be provided by a continuous-deployment system or something checked in to the source tree; you wouldn't use `kubectl set image` since it will get overwritten by the next build.

Answer (score 0):

- If your pod defintion is embedded inside Deployment resource, you can run the `kubectl set image` at the [level of Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment), then "Deployment" resource will take care of rolling update the new revision.
- If you are using pod without Deployment, you need to recreate your pod:

  ```
  ns=my-namepsace # change it as per your namespace
  pd=my-pod-name # change it as per your pod name, .. then:
  kubectl -n $ns get pod $pd -o yaml | kubectl -n $ns replace -f-
  ```